# Dissociate Control zone from Image in a ScatterViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scatterview

I would like to make a selection zone smaller than the ScatterViewItem himself.
I tried many things but nothing worked.I have the following image as a ScatterViewItem :

[image]

I'd like to make ONLY the red circle (and the insideof it) clickable
as a starting point for usual Scatterview manipulations.

Any idea who i should proceed ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you set the visual appearance of the ScatterViewItem by setting its template, you might do something similar to the example shown  below. It sets the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the image to false and overlays it with a smaller transparent circle to receive input.

```
<s:ScatterViewItem>
    <s:ScatterViewItem.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="..." IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Margin="20"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </s:ScatterViewItem.Template>
</s:ScatterViewItem>
```